# Multiple shapes in drawable

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

Is it possible to to have multiple shapes in a single drawable?

I am trying to create "progressDrawable" for seekbar; by making individual circles and offsetting with padding(Not a good idea I guess) in a single drawable resource file.

But doesn't seem to work as it shows in "preview" in Android Studio.
I have just started Android development; please help me figure this out guys. Also I feel there might be a better way to get this done, instead of making these individual circles in drawable file.

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

What I have accomplished so far:

```
  <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekbar_cancel"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekbar_apply"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seeker"
    />
```

custom_seeker.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="7dp" android:right="7dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f06"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="0dp" android:left="2dp" android:bottom="7dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="0dp" android:left="4dp" android:bottom="7dp" android:right="3dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#0f8"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="0dp" android:left="6dp" android:bottom="7dp" android:right="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to to have multiple shapes in a single drawable?

Yes, you should use [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)